# Почему поиск элементов с четным индексом игнорирует элемент с индексом 16?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Программа должна суммировать элементы с четным индексом и умножать на последний элемент. По какой-то причине эта программа при поиске элементов с четным индексом игнорирует элемент с индексом 16.

```
def check(array: list) -> int:
    if len(array) == 0:
        print(0)
    else:
        c=0
        for k in array[::]:
            if (array.index(k) % 2) == 0:
                c= k + c
                print(k,c)
    x = c * array[-1]
    print(x)
    return 0

check([-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41])
```

Comment: Я уже решил задачу иначе, но, все равно, было б интересно узнать в чем загвоздка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цикл с проверкой индекса нужно делать через `enumerate` - это самый понятный, простой и правильный способ:

```
    for i,k in enumerate(array):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            c += k
            print(k,c)
```

Использовать же `.index` неправильно, если элементы в списке повторяются - так будет выдан индекс только первого из повторений элемента в списке.

Простая проверка:

```
    for k in array:
        print(array.index(k),k)
```

Вывод:

```
0 -37
1 -36
2 -19
3 -99
4 29
5 20
6 3
7 -7
8 -64
9 84   <-- 84 встретилось в первый раз
10 36
11 62
12 26
13 -76
14 55
15 -24
9 84   <-- индекс указывает на первое 84
17 49
18 -65
19 41
```

P.S. Так то сама задача решается гораздо проще:

```
arr = [-37,-36,-19,-99,29,20,3,-7,-64,84,36,62,26,-76,55,-24,84,49,-65,41]
print(sum(arr[::2])*arr[-1])
# 1968
```

Comment: а зачем вообще проверять индекс на четность, если можно сразу брать только четные индексы и обойтись без проверок?

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну это же просто иллюстрация принципа. В данном конкретном случае конечно нужно было бы взять слайс и вообще в одну строчку всё написать коротенько. Вопрос же про то, почему данный код криво работает. )

Comment: Да я именно так и решил. Допетрил чуть позже. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что array.index(k) возвращает индекс первого встреченного k.
А для значения 84 этот индекс равен 9... как то так.
В данном случае правильно делать цикл по индексам через генератор.

Answer (score -1):

```
for idx in range(0, len(array), 2): # сразу берём только чётные индексы
    c = c + array[idx]
```

Comment: Я не минусовал, но и не плюсовал, потому что вопрос был про другое, ваш ответ не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну можно подумать, что на этом сайте все ответы отвечают на вопрос :) Иной раз вопрос об одном, ответ о другом. На минус мне все равно (но плюс, конечно, всегда приятнее :D )

Comment: Ну так зачем же множить энтропию? ))  Вполне можно и нужно указывать более правильный вариант кода, но и на суть вопроса при этом тоже хорошо бы ответить.